# How to horizontally align child nodes with the graphdrawing library of TikZ 3.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to left align the "2222" node with the other nodes on the same level (see MWE below). Is this possible using the graphdrawing library of TikZ 3.0? I could not work it out so far.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node={align=left}]
\graph [tree layout, grow'=right, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in,
sibling distance=0.1in]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2222 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE with "2222" not aligned to other nodes on same level]

Comment: You should rather put a solution in an answer rather than a question to keep things tidy and make it easy for people to find things. It is fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Zarko I was able to get a working solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={anchor=west}]
\graph [tree layout, grow'=right, fresh nodes, level distance=3cm,
sibling distance=2ex, head anchor=west]
    {
        4 -> { 
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2222 }
        } 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: MWE Solution]

Answer (score 8):

Instead `every node={align=left}` in `tikzpicture` parameters you should say:

```
every node/.style={anchor=west}
```

Result:

[image]

**Upgrade:** To my taste, regarding to edited questions, the following solution looks nicer:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing, graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
every node/.style={anchor=west}]            % <---
\graph [tree layout, grow'=right, 
        fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in,
        sibling distance=0.1in
                    ]
    {
        4 -> {
          3 -> { 1 -> { 5, " " }, 2,2 },
          3 -> { 1, 2, 2 },
          3 -> [head anchor=west]{ 1, 2, 2222}  % head anchor=west can be 
                                                % mowed to graph preamble
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Note: MWE should be compiled by LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I should have known this! Now I have got  a new problem: How can I align the arrow from "3" to "2222" to point to this anchor instead of the node's center?

Comment: @SimonSchälli, I'm not sure, if >I understand you correctly. Arrow to node `2222` has different outgoing angle as at nodes `2`. This can be compensated by use of  `3 -> { 1, 2, 2222[nudge=(up:-2mm)] }` instead `3 -> { 1, 2, 2222 }`. Try if this gives what you looking for.

Comment: You did understand me correctly. Thanks again for your solution. I did just find another possibility. Adding "head anchor=west" to the graph parameters does what I want. I will add this to my original post.

Comment: @SimonSchälli, I'm glad that you find solution you liked. I still learn graphs and graphsdriwing ...

Comment: @SimonSchälli Your upgraded solution does not work for me only `every node/.style={anchor=west}`. I am on TeXLive 2018: `pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)`, `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex 2015/06/05 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.44)`. Can you confirm your local style adjustment `3 -> [head anchor=west]{ 1, 2, 2222}` still works?